# XCOPY file with different extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

Context, there is an application that generates the files with the same name, but when placing the extension it places a number that increases by one each time it is generated, the application does it that way and I cannot modify it.

Now, I want to copy with XCOPY only the most recent file with name DPD14400 but that varies in its extension, and in turn for the at last file to change the extension to. "Tab", let's say that the following files are in C;

- FILE.001 -> Modification date: 01/01/2020
- FILE.002 -> Modification date: 02/01/2020
- FILE.002 -> Modification date: 03/01/2020
- DPD14400.001 -> Modification date: 01/01/2020
- DPD14400.002 -> Modification date: 02/01/2020
- DPD14400.003 -> Modification date: 03/01/2020
- DPD14400.004 -> Modification date: 04/01/2020
- TEXT.001 -> Modification date: 01/01/2020
- TEXT.002 -> Modification date: 02/01/2020
- TEXT.003 -> Modification date: 03/01/2020

I am trying to do it with that code but it is creating a directory for me with the name of the file and then if the file pastes me, how can I not create the directory and paste it directly in d:

```
xcopy "c:\DPD14400.*" "d:\DPD14400.tab" /y /d /i
```

Thanks for your reply.

Cordially,

Comment: Is that really `dos`, or is it the Windows Command line? That may make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use just copy instead of xcopy. You can get the last file with some dir filters:

```
@echo off

set "mask=DPD*"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:-d /t:c %mask%') do (
    set "last_file=%%~fa"
    set "last_file_without_extension=%%~na"
    goto:break
)
:break

copy /y "%last_file%" "d:\%last_file_without_extension%.tab"
```